# How to prevent data from edited manually in DB?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, database-design

I've a table with few rows. These rows should be modified only via my application, ie, I need to prevent manual editing by using client (such as HeidiSQL). Is it possible to prevent it?

I can do the following:

- Encrypt the data
- Encrypt the connection string
- Use hash code

But I want to know, is it possible to prevent manual editing the data in DB?

Does any DB vendor (Oracle, SQL, MySQL) provide these type of functionality?

Comment: The best way to prevent a user to edited manually the DB is remove him/her permission, and give permission only to execute some Store procedures or function.

Comment: No, the client doesn't send an id to RDMS, so you can't allow to access DB from some clients and disallow from the other. Actually, it's useless, because the id could be changed easily.

Comment: You could not expose the SQL connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set user permissions on your db. This is possible in all the DBmanagers you mentioned.

Example:
In this case I would make 3 user permissions types

1. a user with read/write permissions (for your application)
2. A user with read permissions (for general users)
3. An admin user with read/write + DBOWNER permissions (for troubleshooting, changing/adding columns and tables...)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an after logon trigger to detect the client and raise an exception :

```
create or replace trigger prevent_sqldeveloper
 after logon on database
declare
  v_program varchar2(48);
  v_sid     number;
  v_serial# number;
begin
  select sid, serial#, program into v_sid, v_serial#, v_program
    from v$session where sid=sys_context('userenv', 'sid');
  if (v_program like 'SQL Developer%') then
    raise_application_error(-20001,
      'You''re not allowed to connect from SQL*Developer');
  end if;
end prevent_sqldeveloper;
/
```

Regards

Comment: This won't help at all as the client application sends that information and it can easily be changed (especially with JDBC). So someone who really wants to change the data simply sends a different application name.

Comment: The 1st request was to prevent manual editing. i agree that some bad guy who know what he is doing can workaround this solution. But if the goal is to secure completely the db, there is options like TDE & security (payable) for this.